# Transforming a quadratic constraint into a linear constraint

Tags: linear-programming, python, linearization

I have a problem with a quadratic constraint and I want to transform it into a linear constraint. This would help to reduce the computational time of my problem.
Following constraint should be linearized.

$(w_{s,t,i} * o_{s,t,j}) - (w_{s,t,j} * o_{s,t,i} )<= 1$

The variable $w$ in this constraint stands for the workforce of skill $s$ in month $t$ in salary step $i$. The variable o stands for the overtime worked of skill s in month $t$ in salary step $i$ or $j$.
This constraint should compare the overtime worked of the workforce in the specific salary step and compare it to the overtime worked of the other salary steps in $i$ or $j$.
This constraint should limit the overtime hour worked per worker to smaller than $1$ between each salary step.

Comment: Are $o$ and $w$ both continuous?

Comment: Yes both are continuous variables

Comment: So both are decision variables? And for my understanding, what is the unit of $w$? Also, is the left $o_{stj}$ supposed to be $o_{sti}$, or is it correct the way you stated in your question?

Comment: Yeah so both are decision Variables. And w is the Workforce in FTEs. So Basically the constraint should check that each worker should work almost the same amount of overtime. But I Don't know each worker so I have to divide the number of workers In each salary step by the number of overtime they work of each salary step and compare them between each other. That's why I have j instead of I to indicate that these are not the same salary steps.

Comment: You say that you have to divide. But in the constraint, you are multiplying overtime with the workforce.

Comment: Yes I actually want this constraint $w_{s,t,i} / o_{s,t,i} - w_{s,t,j} / o_{s,t,j} <= 1 $ since Gurobi doesn't want division between the decision variables I just multiplied both sides in order to get the constraint above. Hope this helps

Comment: You forgot to multiply the RHS.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be $o_{sti}/w_{sti}$ (same with $j$), since you want to compare the hours of overtime per worker, and not the other way around?

Comment: You are absolutely right I just confused myself. Nethertheless the quadratic constraint should work. But for the logic you are right.

Comment: @Adri, is the question still relevant?

Comment: @A.Omidi yes it is

Comment: @Adri, sorry for my late. As a rapid answer, if you ensure the written constraint is true, you can linearize that by MacCormick inequalities. As the second attempt, would you explain more on the problem you are facing? I am not sure to understand the whole of the second paragraph you mentioned. It would be great if you could give a simple example.